# Django Celery - Use Django DB broker on production for small application?

Tags: django, django-celery

I've seen this asked before, but haven't seen a solid answer.

I have a very small production application (200-500 users, hitting the site sparingly) on Heroku.

I have a handful of tasks, but nothing too crazy. Would I be ok runnning with django_db as my broker?

I'm only running one celery worker on heroku with 3 concurrent processes (for heroku memory reasons).

> Using more than a few workers (can lead to messages being executed
>   multiple times).

Comment: The limitation is per worker instance, not the number of child processes that instance runs with. E.g. starting one `celery worker --concurrency=10` should be fine, but not several `celery worker`'s running.

Comment: What is the reason behind having troubles with multiple worker instances? Not locking a task quick enough and the other worker grabbing it?

Comment: There's no locking whatsoever.  It shouldn't be too hard to add for someone who wants it (I don't have the time do do it).  The code for the database message transport was originally from a project called django-queue-service.

Comment: So is that the reason it might start running messages twice? (just trying to learn)